# grpc python support multithreading on client and server

Tags: python, multithreading, grpc

I want to know Is grpc python support multithreading? please share some reference.
I have written the code in the single thread but don't know how to write in multithread.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work

Answer (score 12):

gRPC Python does support multithreading on both client and server. As for server, you will create the server with a thread pool, so it is multithreading in default. As for client, you can create a channel and pass it to multiple Python thread and then create a stub for each thread. Also, since the channel is managed in C instead of Python, create multiple channels to the same server in the same process won't give you any performance advantage.

```
import threading
import grpc

def worker(channel):
    stub = your_pb2_grpc.YourStub(channel)
    ...YOUR WORK WITH STUB

channel = grpc.insecure_channel(<YOUR PORT>)
your_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(channel,))
your_thread.start()
```

Also, if you intent to use multiprocessing instead of multithreading, you can reference here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16001 and https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/fork_support.md.

Answer (score 0):

The ThreadPoolExecutor can be used to execute the async calls in parallel at client side:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
   results = list(executor.map(one_async_call, new_requests))
```

where one_sync_call is function that will be called asynchronously and new_requests is list of requests.The async_call function is mapped to the list of requests.